# I am trying to fill an array of size [i][j] with data from a txt file in C

Tags: arrays, file, input

Here is an example of what I have done. Where is my logic faulty? I open up the file and declare an array of some size. Yet I cant seem to fill the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /*open the file from use input*/
    printf("what file stores your cities temperature data?\n");
    char filename[20];
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp=fopen(filename, "r");
    if (ifp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File Open Error...");
    }
    else
    {
        /*declare an array and fill with file data?*/
        double cityarray [6102][4];

        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<6102;i++)
        {

            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            {
                fscanf(ifp, "%.1lf", cityarray[i][j]);
                printf("%.1lf\t",cityarray[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        fclose (ifp);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your output? Does your array have any content, partially filled?

Comment: posting the error message would be useful.

Comment: What happens? Do you get any error message?

Comment: What is your text file's format?  Have you tried to see where it fails?

Comment: my output is the array but it is all zeros. No error messages, it compiles. the text file would look something like the files here. http://academic.udayton.edu/kissock/http/Weather/gsod95-current/ALBIRMIN.txt

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%.1lf", &cityarray[i][j]);
```

Comment: when I use fscanf without the '&' I get four columns of '0.0' a few hundred rows long. when I use the '&' the output starts the same with four columns of '0.0' but then a mess of random numbers at the end.

Comment: i was told to add "-1 -1 -1 -1" to the end of the file but i'm not sure how to use that yet. I just want to understand the concept of reading a file like this into a 2D array.

Comment: Try to eliminate the inner loop and use this instead: 
    fscanf(ifp,"%.1lf\t%.1lf\t%.1lf\t%.1lf\n",&cityarray[i][j]);

Comment: i got a single column of zeros.I thought it might be the location of my file that is causing the problem but im sure it would return back NULL as i put in my if statement

Comment: The ifp is just a integer, so try to print it after open to see if it is 0 or something... OR try to put in the code the filename to be sure it is correct.

Comment: ok, i  get a "file open error". maybe it is my file. Maybe I should try it with a smaller more controlled file and array.